# What does the plus sign next to the price of an app in the App Store mean?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore

There is often a plus sign in the upper left corner of the price button for an app. Even some free apps have this plus sign.

[image: image from AppStore]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It means that it is a universal app, able to run on the iPad and iPhone.

Comment: I thought it means the app has in-app purchases. That would be a lot more useful - and a more intuitive use for that + icon.

Comment: Maybe apps with in app purchase should have two currency symbols. $$ or ££ It sure would be nice, but I doubt it would fly.

Comment: Do you want to be looking for apps with in-app purchases? It makes sense to do an icon if its something you want to quickly find (such as ability to run the app on both devices).

Comment: In-App purchases are considered extras and are 'less important' than conveying that the app itself is a universal binary.

Answer (score -4):

It means there are in-app purchases available under that app.  You can turn that feature off under your General Settings, Restrictions.

Comment: The accepted answer is clear here - the + indicates the device works on iPad sized screens as well as iPhone sized screens by having code and graphic layouts to support both from the same app.