# How to remove + sign from app not using In-App purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

I do not use it, or at least haven't set it up l, but App Store show my app as it would use In App purchase. How can I avoid to show it?

Comment: The plus sign next to the buy/download button indicates that you get both an iPad and iPhone version with one purchase, is this what you're referring to?

Comment: wow, serious, + means universal app?

Comment: See [here for example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/what-does-the-plus-sign-next-to-the-price-of-an-app-in-the-app-store-mean)